# php arrays, timestamps and loops

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following code. The $results array outputs like so

`[1] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 4429 [post_date_gmt] => 2015-03-05 11:04:18 )`

In the second loop I'm calculating the difference between todays time and the postdate. The right results are returned in the IF statement, however to get here I've lost the ID from the original `$results` array. I need to change a value in the database based on ID if `$difference < 72`

So the question is - Is it possible to get to the IF statement whilst keeping the ID and post_date_gmt together?

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results(
"SELECT ID, post_date_gmt
FROM wp_posts
WHERE post_type = 'job_listing'"
); 
print_r($results);
$jobids = array();
$jobdates = array();
foreach($results as $oneitem) {
    $jobids[]=$oneitem->ID;
    $jobdates[]=$oneitem->post_date_gmt;
}

foreach($jobdates as $value) {
    $postdate = $value;
    $today = time();
    $postdate = strtotime($postdate);
    //echo $postdate;
    $difference = round(abs($today-$postdate)/60/60);
    if($difference < 72) {
        echo $difference;
        //change a value in the database where the id matches the id from the $results array
    }
}
?>
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are building your arrays, why not use the job ID as the key for the jobdates array?

```
foreach($results as $oneitem) {
    $jobdates[$oneitem->ID]=$oneitem->post_date_gmt;
}
```

Then when you call that array for the second foreach loop, call the key as well `foreach($jobdates as $key => $value)` and it will be available to use and properly associated.

Comment: Thanks @GeoffAtkins. So $key would then be the ID?

Comment: @IanButler - That's right. You're using the array key to carry the ID. Just a word of warning, this will only work if the IDs are all unique as the keys of an array must be unique. If you have duplicate IDs then you'll need to create a multidimensional array to carry the IDs and job dates across together.